# How can i call a function on run time on button click as you can see in below code

Tags: javascript

```
function createButton(){
    var btnDisplay = document.createElement("button");
    btnDisplay.innerHTML="Display Value";
    btnDisplay.backgroundColor="green";
    btnDisplay.onclick="alrt()";
    var divCon = document.getElementById("detailcal");
    divCon.appendChild(btnDisplay);

}
```

Here I am create crate a function that create a button and I have set a attribute for it, attribute is displaying on a page but function `alrt();` is not displaying on page code.

not working any solution to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method of element:

```
function createButton(){
    var btnDisplay = document.createElement("button");
    btnDisplay.innerHTML="Display Value";
    btnDisplay.backgroundColor="green";
    btnDisplay.setAttribute("onclick", "alert('hello')");
    var divCon = document.getElementById("detailcal");
    divCon.appendChild(btnDisplay);

}
createButton();
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO it's better if you could avoid inlin-events and use `addEventListener()` or `onclick` instead :

```
btnDisplay.onclick=function() { alrt();  };
//OR
btnDisplay.addEventListener('click', alrt, false);
```

Hopet this helps.